# Pagerank is equivalent to degree centrality

Tags: graphs

Can someone explain why pagerank defined for *undirected* graph with no damping factor is equivalent to the degree?

$\sum_{j\in N(i)}{\frac{p(j)}{d(j)}} = d(i)$

I looked up every book I could, but they all say it's trivial and skip the proof, making me feel stupid.

Comment: If the pagerank of vertex $i$ is $p(i) = \sum_{j \in N(i)} \frac{p(j)}{d(j)}$, (which I think is the definition of pagerank on undirected graph, without dumping factor), then we can check that if $p(j) =  d(j), \forall j \in V$, then the above relation holds for all vertices. Of course, if we restrict $\sum_{i}p(i)=1$, then the above is only true up to a scaling factor: $p(i) = \frac{1}{2|E|}d(i)$, where $E$ is the edge set.

Comment: Yes, but then where undirectedness of a graph appear?

Comment: I believe that in the definition of pagerank for an arbitrary graph, $N(i)$ is the in-neighbor (vertices that point to vertex $i$) and $d(j)$ in the denominator is the out-degree of vertex $j$. Is that correct? But if the graph is undirected then in and out degree are equal, and $|N(i)| = d(i)$.

Comment: I think you may need to make two more assumptions about the graph, to make a proof work. I think you need to assume that the graph is connected, and that there exists a loop of odd length.

Comment: And why the second assumption you need?